# Spring Boot passing value / using method inside the application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

For example:

I have a class called Path.java

In Path.java, I have getter method "getPort()" that returns int 8080

In application.properties, I want to use     server.port = "getPort()"

How?

I want to externalize the datasource. I already have a class that grabs the information from the external .txt file. I need to use this class inside the application.properties.

Like, spring.datasource.url = ??getURL()??

Comment: Properties doesn't work that way. Their purpose is to gather a static content provided for the application as configuration.

Comment: The answer is NO, you can achieve like this in the existing spring boot properties file.

Comment: best way to do it is pass as runtime variables

Comment: There are ways, but they're far more complicated than the direct approach of extracting the information before launch (usually in a shell script) and setting the environment variable `PORT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking how you get the `port` in your `Path.java` . Then just reuse that information.  There is no way to call a method in a properties file.